# One button to control another button on many user controls

Tags: vb.net

Hey and sorry for another strange question...

I have 25 `UserControl`s with a `Start_Button` on each of them - this `Start_Button` can either be `Visible` or not depending on whether the `UserControl` is active. On my `form1` I have a `Start_All` button.

I would like to simulate a click of all the `UserControl`'s `Start_Buttons` which are visible only.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Winforms or webforms? In general, instead of simulating click-events expose a method for the start-functionality and  call this method from the `Start_Button.Click`-event. Then you can call this method from wherever you want, your code remains readable and reusable.

Comment: I've tried making a list of all the usercontrols. Making a boolean variable of whether they are visible or not. And then trying to somehow use a for loop with an if statement to `.performclick()` if value of each usercontrol is visible... But I couldn't get that to work xD @equisde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of simulating click-events expose a method for the start-functionality and  call this method from the `Start_Button.Click`-event. Then you can use this method from wherever you want. On this way your code remains readable and reusable.

You should also provide an `Active` property in your `UserControl` which you can simply link to your start-button's `Visible`-property.

Presuming that the user-controls are in a container-control like `Panel`:

```
Public Sub StartAll()
    Dim allActiveUserControls = 
        From uc In controlPanel.Controls.OfType(Of MyUserControlType)()
        Where uc.Active
    For Each uc In allActiveUserControls 
        uc.Start()
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is an example for the `Active` property:

```
Public Property Active As Boolean
    Get
        Return StartButton.Visible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        StartButton.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and here are the `Start` method and the event-handlers:

```
Public Sub Start()
    ' Do Something ... '
End Sub

Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Start_All_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Start_All.Click
    StartAll()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm struggling to grasp this solution :3

Comment: @AmatureCoder: what exactly don't you understand? `MyUserControlType` is the type of your `UserControl`(replace it with the correct type). The snippet that starts with `From uc In controlPanel` is a LINQ-query.

Comment: @AmatureCoder: that's the code that belongs into your `Start_All`-button's click event handler.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I start typing var into my `btn_Start_All_Click` sub, it doesn't recognise var as anything?

Comment: @AmatureCoder: i have edited my answer to show the `StartAll` method and to fix the `var`-bug, i mixed C# with VB.NET ;)

Comment: This is the error i get now - 'controlpanel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @AmatureCoder: that's the `Panel` (or any other container-control) i have spoken about. It's needed because i'm searching for your controls via `Enumerable.OfType` on the `Controls`-property. If the `UserControl`'s aren't in any control but are on top of the `Form` (or `Page` in ASP.NET), you can use `Me.Controls.OfType....` or use this `Panel` and put all the controls into it since it increases maintainability of your code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ai Ai Ai it works :) You are brilliant thanks a bunch<3 I Hope it doesn't take me too long before I'm at a stage where I'm half as good as you :)